# When does an invalid_request error happen at the Flattr api?

Tags: api, flattr

It isn't clear to me, when exactly an `invalid_request` error happens. Does this also happen if the token to authorise isn't valid anymore?

Thanks, udo

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is the result of an unauthorized request, for that you should be getting an '401 unauthorized' error.

It is more likely the result of not sending the proper parameters. Although the documentation says that the error in that case should be invalid_parameters, in some events an '400 invalid_request' error will be returned instead.